# Docker-compose: Replacement for the extends keyword

Tags: docker, docker-compose

From the docker [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/):

> Docker Compose’s **extends** keyword enables sharing of common
>   configurations among different files, or even different projects
>   entirely. Extending services is useful if you have several services
>   that reuse a common set of configuration options. Using extends you
>   can define a common set of service options in one place and refer to
>   it from anywhere.

For some reason this feature was  [removed in version 3](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#version-3).

Found also [this thread](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4315), but it is inactive for 2 years.

I'm trying to find a replacement for this feature in the newer versions.

**Would like to hear if somebody found a replacement for `extends`.**

Thanks.

Comment: This has apparently been replaced (sort of....) by using several compose files: https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/2051

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are 2 ways to achieve what you need, you can decide to use one of them or both at the same time as they work slightly differently:

### Multiple compose files

You can specify multiple compose files when running a docker compose command, you could for instance set up your project with:

```
docker-compose -f config1.yml -f config2.yml up
```

You could also use an environment variable to specify your files:

```
COMPOSE_FILE=config1.yml:config2.yml docker-compose up
```

What happens is that docker compose creates a single config merging what you defined in each of them.
Here the documentation showing [how to merge multiple compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/#specifying-multiple-compose-files).

You can also generate your final config file running the [`config` command](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/config/).

### YAML Anchors

Since docker compose files are basically YAML files, you can take advantage of YAML Anchors to define a block of properties and reuse them in multiple parts of your config.

For example:

```
version: '3'

common: &common
  image: "myrepo/myimage"
  restart: "unless-stopped"
  volumes:
    - "volume:/mnt/myvolume"

services:
  service1:
    <<: *common
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"

  service2:
    <<: *common
    environment:
      - MYENV: value
```